# Read perl file handle with $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR as a regex

Tags: perl

I'm looking for a way to read from a file handle line by line (and then execute a function on each line) with the following twist: what I want to treat as a "line" shall be terminated by varying characters and not just a single character that I define as `$/`. I now that `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR` or `$/` do not support regular expressions or passing a list of characters to be treated as line terminators and this is where my problem lies.

My file handle comes from stdout of a process. Thus, I cannot seek inside the file handle and the full content is not available immediately but is produced bit by bit as the process is executed. I want to be able to attach things like a timestamp to each "line" the process produces using a function that I called `handler` in my examples. Each line should be handled as soon as it gets produced by the program.

Unfortunately, I can only come up with a way that either executes the `handler` function immediately but seems horribly inefficient or a way that uses a buffer but will only lead to "grouped" calls of the `handler` function and thus, for example, produce wrong timestamps.

In fact, in my specific case, my regex would even be very simple and just read `/\n|\r/`. So for this particular problem I don't even need full regex support but just the possibility to treat more than one character as the line terminator. But `$/` doesn't support this.

Is there an efficient way to solve this problem in Perl?

Here is some quick pseudo-perl code to demonstrate my two approaches:

### read the input file handle byte-by-byte

This would look like this:

```
my $acc = "";
while (read($fd, my $b, 1)) {
    $acc .= $b;
    if ($acc =~ /someregex$/) {
        handler($acc);
        $acc = "";
    }
}
```

The advantage here is, that `handler` gets immediately dispatched once enough bytes are read. The disadvantage is, that we do string appending and check the regex for every single byte we read from `$fd`.

### read the input file handle with blocks of X-byte at a time

This would look like this:

```
my $acc = "";
while (read($fd, my $b, $bufsize)) {
    if ($b =~ /someregex/) {
        my @parts = split /someregex/, $b;
        # for brevity lets assume we always get more than 2 parts...
        my $first = shift @parts;
        handler(acc . $first);
        my $last = pop @parts;
        foreach my $part (@parts) {
            handler($part);
        }
        $acc = $last;
    }
}
```

The advantage here is, that we are more efficient as we only check every `$bufsize` bytes. The disadvantage is, that the execution of `handler` has to wait until `$bufsize` bytes have been read.

Comment: How do you get `$fd`?

Comment: @Сухой27 that's what I was getting at. If `RS` in awk is more than one char, it's a regex. Piping through something like `awk 'BEGIN{RS="[aeiou]"; FS="\n"} {print;}'` would split on all vocals and turn the lines into something that `$/` can process. Though `\n` might be something you'd want to preserve, so use a BELL or a `\0` or whatever instead.

Comment: @simbabque OP could also pipe his input through perl filter, `perl -pe 'tr|\r|\n|' file | script.pl` as he is only looking for `/\r|\n/` separator.

Comment: @simbabque @Сухой27 Your solutions destroy the information which line terminator was used for each line. So the `handler` will not be able to reconstruct the original information from what it gets.

Comment: @Сухой27 That will not work because this will still wait for a newline and only do the translation once it found a `\n`. Try out this: `{ echo -ne "blubber\r"; sleep 1; echo -n "blabber\r"; sleep 1; echo "foo" } | perl -pe 'tr|\r|\n|'`

Comment: @simbabque The `awk` solution doesn't work as expected because it will not immediately print a "line" once the terminator as defined by `RS` is encountered. Try running this: `{ echo -ne "blubber\r"; sleep 1; echo -n "blabber\r"; sleep 1; echo "foo" } | awk 'BEGIN{RS="[\r\n]"; FS="\n"} {print;}'`

Comment: I learned a new error message. _Setting $/ to a REGEXP reference is forbidden_ :)

Comment: [`Acme::InputRecordSeparatorIsRegexp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Acme::InputRecordSeparatorIsRegexp) with a `bufsize` of 1?

Answer (score 2):

Setting $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR to a regex wouldn't help, because Perl's `readline` uses buffered IO, too. The trick is to use your second approach but with unbuffered `sysread` instead of `read`. If you `sysread` from a pipe, the call will return as soon as data is available, even if the whole buffer couldn't be filled (at least on Unix).

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by nwellnhof allowed me to implement a solution to this problem:

```
my $acc = "";
while (1) {
    my $ret = sysread($fh, my $buf, 1000);
    if ($ret == 0) {
        last;
    }
    # we split with a capturing group so that we also retain which line
    # terminator was used
    # a negative limit is used to also produce trailing empty fields if
    # required
    my @parts = split /(\r|\n)/, $buf, -1;
    my $numparts = scalar @parts;
    if ($numparts == 1) {
        # line terminator was not found
        $acc .= $buf;
    } elsif ($numparts >= 3) {
        # first match needs special treatment as it needs to be
        # concatenated with $acc
        my $first = shift @parts;
        my $term = shift @parts;
        handler($acc . $first . $term);
        my $last = pop @parts;
        for (my $i = 0; $i < $numparts - 3; $i+=2) {
            handler($parts[$i] . $parts[$i+1]);
        }
        # the last part is put into the accumulator. This might
        # just be the empty string if $buf ended in a line
        # terminator
        $acc = $last;
    }
}
# if the output didn't end with a linebreak, handle the rest
if ($acc ne "") {
    handler($acc);
}
```

My tests show that indeed `sysread` will return even before having read 1000 characters if there is a pause in the input stream. The code above takes care to concatenate multiple messages of length 1000 and split messages with a lesser length or multiple terminators correctly.

Please shout if you see any bug in above code.